# Selenide + JUnit5 + BrowserStack: Parametrized test miltiplied with browsers

Tags: gradle, junit5, browserstack, selenide

My setup is:

- Selenide
- Junit5
- gradle

I using parametrized tests to run same tests with different users.

On top of that, I want to add BrowserStack.

So eg. having test

```
@ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}; user: {0}")
@ArgumentsSource(...)
public void exampleTest(TestUser user) {
```

I want to end up with, eg.

- (0) exampleTest; user 1; Firefox
- (1) exampleTest; user 2; Firefox
- (2) exampleTest; user 1; Chrome
- (3) exampleTest; user 2; Chrome

Problem is that BrowserStack example for junit5 is (a) written for plain selenium, not selenide and (b) doesn't seem to work with ParameterizedTest.

Have anyone attempted such setup, and can point be to right direction? I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I can use out-of-the-box solution ;)

I'm also open to use SauceLabs instead of Browserstack.

Answer (score 0):

I think, a good approach is to isolate your test domains

Browsers switching in test runtime is not good solution since Selenide has static configuration

You have to split test configuring and test running

1 part - your configuration domain: external browsers configuration (you can implement this approach via JUnit5 extensions) Example - JUnit5 extension that configure your test libs (Selenide, etc) according to some external env variable

2 part - your test domain - parameterized tests via your test data (users, conditions, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Official Browserstack documentation for running the Selenide test parallel on various browsers.

- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/getting-started/java/selenide/run-tests-in-parallel
- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/getting-started/java/selenide#introduction

Also, you can take help from their GitHub Repository for Selenide with TestNG, where they have used @parameters with their test cases.

- https://github.com/browserstack/selenide-browserstack.git

I hope this helps.

Thanks